# Should there be an auto-freeze or auto remove from common circulation regex?

Tags: discussion, spam

If the powers that be take a look at recent spam flags for:

Watch!!

on AskUbuntu specifically for sure, you'll see what I mean.  It could be a significant indicator at least for a time.

Other suggested, but more complicated indicators have included extended white-space.

A recent conversation involving loads of spam starts here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8523637#8523637

A portion of it certainly complies to those rules.

Edit:
It has been common for a couple weeks now for those particular spam surges.  Always TV or sports, but the programs vary.  They used to be isolated one or two at a time.  Now they are 10-20 in the space of an hour.

As @balpha noted: The question really is should "Watch!!" with multiple exclamation points be in the list.

Comment: It all got deleted... what's the problem?

Comment: It could be more efficient.  If grep "Watch!!" or any other magical indicator is possible, it should probably exist.  It's like saying "Assembly got it done when it needed to, we don't need C since it's a macro assembler" or "We don't need C++ since it's just a design pattern and additional template library for C".  While all statements are theoretically true, it doesn't mean it's the best way to do it.

Comment: This question is a little confusing for those not in the know, or who can't view the deleted posts, you may want to put in a bit more detail about what the actual problem is.

Comment: Such a blacklist already exists, the question is just if a term like "Watch!!" should really be added just because of a singular event (all those spam posts where made within about 10 minutes).